# Atualizar conteúdo somente quando acessar a div

Tags: jquery

Tenho um formulário step-by-step do qual a cada etapa salvo no banco de dados as informações. Na última etapa trago as informações salvas da seguinte forma com jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function mostrar(){   
    $(document).ready(function(){                      
            $.ajax({               
                    type:'post', 
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: 'atualizar.php',
                    success: function(dados){

                       for(var i=0;dados.length>i;i++){
                           $('#listar').append(dados[0]);
                           $('#listar').append(dados[i].id+'</td><td>'+dados[i].nome+'</td><td>'+dados[i].email+'</td></tr>');
                       }

                    console.log(dados);    
                    }
            });
    });   
}
setInterval(mostrar, 2000);
</script>
```

Está funcionando perfeitamente, mas nesse caso estou atualizando por 02 segundos a div e gostaria de saber se é possível atualizar somente quando acessar a div na última etapa. O HTML está dessa forma:

```
<fieldset>
    <!-- Última etapa do step-by-step -->
    <h4>Confirme seus dados:</h4>

    <div id="listar"></div>

    <form role="form" action="" method="post" id="contact-form">
    <div class="f1-buttons">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-previous">Alterar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Finalizar</button>
    </div>
    </form>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: defina "quando acessar a div"

Comment: Esse é aquele projeto que vc tava fazendo?

Comment: Olá DvD. Isso, mas houve mudanças no decorrer do projeto :(

Comment: Olá Paulo Roberto. Na verdade seria ao acessar a última etapa onde a div que me refiro se encontra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode saber quando está no último passo verificando se no `fieldset` ativo existe um botão com o texto "Finalizar". Essa verificação é feita na função abaixo:

```
function scroll_to_class(element_class, removed_height) {
    var scroll_to = $(element_class).offset().top - removed_height;
    if($(window).scrollTop() != scroll_to) {
        $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: scroll_to}, 0);
    }
   if( $('fieldset:visible').find('button:contains("Finalizar")').length == 1){
      // última etapa. Faça o que deseja aqui
      alert("Última etapa");
   }
}
```

Comment: Perfeito DvD. Muito obrigado mais uma vez.

Answer (score 0):

O ideal é que você crie uma função que identifique quando você está em um formulário com a opção focus.

Quando estiver editando, não atualize.

E quanto a salvar os dados, imagino que seja melhor guardar em sessão ou cookie e só no final preencher o BD.

Isso vai evitar desgaste de memória de banco de lhe trazer performance, pense sempre nisso.

Comment: Compreendo Dávil, mas as informações contidas em cada passo são grandes e caso ocorra a queda da luz ou internet, as informações estarão salvas e com isso o usuário não terá que refazer todos os processos, bastando apenas se logar no sistema.